# Can I get the history.back() function to work in Chrome when using the file:// protocol?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-files

I'm building an application in an environment where I'm restricted to using the local file system and a browser (i.e. running a server isn't an option). I have a generic 'go back' link on numerous pages that mainly just calls `history.back()`. It looks something like the following:

```
function goBack(evt) {
    // Check to see if override is needed here

    // If no override needed, call history.back()
    history.back();
}

$('#my-back-button').click(goBack);
```

This code works fine in Firefox and IE6 (don't ask), but fails in Chrome. Any suggestions as to why and/or possible workarounds?

I've also tried `history.go(-1);` which does not work either.

Comment: Do some Google searches on "chrome back button not working" this might be a browser bug, your code is fine. I would submit a report at Google.

Comment: @MikeL. Thanks for the tip, but Googling the issue has proven unproductive. Is there any way to confirm this is an actual bug?

Comment: Try this: _chrome workaround for triggering click events on <a> elements_ `$.fn.forwardEvent = function(event) {
  this.each(function() {
   if (this.dispatchEvent) {
    if (event.originalEvent) {
     event = event.originalEvent
    }
    try {
     this.dispatchEvent(event);
    } catch(error) {
     $(this).trigger(event);
    }
   }
   else {
    $(this).trigger(event);
   }
  });
  return this;
 };`

Comment: It's likely the same issue as http://crbug.com/11001 but there doesn't seem to be an existing bug report mentioning specifically local files. Then again, when I tested this `history.back()` worked just fine for local files (Chrome 18).

Comment: Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815838/webkit-chrome-history-back-1-onclick-vs-href-resolved

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For some reason in chrome, you have to add return false after calling history.go(-1)

Change your function to:

```
function goBack(evt) {
// Check to see if override is needed here

// If no override needed, call history.back()
history.go(-1);
return false;
}
```

Comment: That is the correct way to do it, so apparently Google forces you to do it the right way.

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    function goBack(evt) {
    // Check to see if override is needed here

    // If no override needed, call history.back()
    history.back();
    $('#my-back-button').forwardEvent('click');
}

$('#my-back-button').click(goBack);

/**
* chrome workaround for triggering click events
* @param {event} event  event
* @return {undefined}   Returns undefined
*/
    $.fn.forwardEvent = function(event) {
        this.each(function() {
            if (this.dispatchEvent) {
                if (event.originalEvent) {
                    event = event.originalEvent
                }
                try {
                    this.dispatchEvent(event);
                } catch(error) {
                    $(this).trigger(event);
                }
            }
            else {
                $(this).trigger(event);
            }
        });
        return this;
    };
});
</script>
<input type="button" value="<<<<" id="my-back-button">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmmm. I'm sorry but this just seems to create an infinite recursion. The issue isn't the $('#my-back-button') not receiving the click event, but rather that history.back() does nothing.

Comment: Well, I've tested it in chrome vs. Your original code, and it works. With "file:///" protocol etc. Didn't work for You?

Comment: Ok, epic fail here, because it works for me anyway, without event forwarding... Could You paste the exact code of page used for testing? Stripped from unncessary stuff of course, bare minimum.

Answer (score 1):

var referrer =  document.referrer;
window.location.replace(referrer);

Use this it will work

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome use below code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:history.go(-1);return false;" style="text-decoration:underline;">Back</a>
```

Only this code will work..

I hope it will help...
Happy coding.. :)

Comment: In general, using "onclick" (and similar) to set event handlers is considered bad practice. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice, for more information.

Answer (score -1):

late to the party...  here is another solution:  you can close the window following the window.history.go(-1).  this will work because chrome will keep the window open so it will read the next line.  other browsers will simply go back.

```
<script>
alert("Success!");
window.history.go(-1);
window.close();
</script>
```

Comment: From the question: "I've also tried history.go(-1); which does not work either."

Comment: it works for all other browsers except chrome, so just add the close script after the window open call and it will close out that window and be back where you started if chrome opened a new tab which is usually the problem.

Comment: The question is about Chrome and your answer doesn't work according to the question itself. There is already an accepted answer and your answer doesn't add anything.

Comment: my answer is about chrome and it is a solution to the original problem.