# history.back function not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get the history.back() function to work in Chrome when using the file:// protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423439/can-i-get-the-history-back-function-to-work-in-chrome-when-using-the-file-p)

I have used the `history.back()` function in JavaScript to go to the previous page.
It seems to work fine in all browsers except chrome.
Any solution for this?

Comment: It would be better if you can post some of your code for better evaluation.

Comment: history.back();
window.open("<%= nvdisplayurl %>",'name','height=600,width=800,scrollbars=1');

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
history.back()
```

you could try

```
history.go(-1);
```